# How to reference the contents of a variable in a keyboard macro definition?

Tags: keyboard-macros

I have a macro called `f5`, which I globally bind the keyboard key `<f5>` to:

```el
(fset 'f5
      [?i ?\[ ?* ?* ?P ?1 ?  ?\] escape ?h ?a])

(global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'f5)
```

So when I press f5, it inserts `[**P1 ]`, and backs up the cursor and leaves me in input mode, which is fine.

But I have reached a stage where, depending on what I am doing, I don't want it to always insert "P1". Sometimes I might like it to insert, say, "P2". What I really want is that it inserts the content of a variable, which variable I can set depending on what I am doing.  But I don't know how to reference the contents of a variable in a macro definition. Surely this is possible; how is it done?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval-expression` when recording your macro.

<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(insert MYVARNAME)` <kbd>RET</kbd>